# Nokia paired via bluetooth AND windows after reboot — possible?

Tags: windows, bluetooth

My Nokia phone (5800) works well with Ubuntu after bluetooth pairing.
When I reboot to Windows (seven, in my case), it doesn't — I have to remove it from 'Paired bluetooth devices' and then add again.

The story repeats when I boot to Ubuntu after windows. I have to remove the phone from known devices and pair it again.

Apparently, there are secret keys created after each pairing which are different between my Ubuntu and Windows installations (or something alike).

How do I make my phone recognize both Ubuntu and Windows — or how do I make Ubuntu (or Windows) use the same secret keys as the other OS — or …?

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.

Answer (score 0):

Try having your phone create the key, or optionally, you can enter your own key.

To do this, find the computer from on your phone, and choose a key when it asks for one.

Comment: today I've tried this on purpose — removing the pairing from both OSs; then establishing pairings again from the phone. Didn't work :(

Comment: that's mighty odd - I've never had this problem. Are you using an internal adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to connect with both OS's? The hardware MAC is the same on your computer but the secret keys are going to be implementation-dependent.

Comment: Yes, the same devices. Different OSs on PC.